# Is there an easy way to invert colors?

Tags: screen, accessibility

iOS has a nice option in the accessibility menu that allows you to invert the screen colors. Does Android have anything like this?

Comment: What is the main reason for this though? I saw it on PC too, but no idea what's its uses are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Android 5.0 Lollipop, the feature is built-in as one of accessibility options.

1. Open **Settings**
2. Select **Accessibility**
3. Below **Display** section, toggle **Color inversion**.

After toggling it for the first time, the "Invert colors" toggle will be added to the quick settings menu.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a built-in feature on Nexus devices, but Samsung devices have this in the accessibility settings.

Inverting all colours isn't much use, as some apps have 
light text on a dark background, and some apps have dark text on a light background. Making text easier to read is better achieved by increasing the text size, which is an option on all Android devices (also in the accessibility settings).

Comment: If you really want to make your phone look cool, learn some OpenGL programming and make your own live wallpaper. http://shadertoy.com/ has some cool ideas. It's a good use for school maths too!

Answer (score 1):

If your device is **rooted** and your Android version is at least **Android 4.4 KitKat**, you could try [CF.lumen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.lumen) (free, pro version also available). The app is actually a screen filter which supports automation based on time/brightness, but it also supports color inversion.

> **Color filters**
>
> Several filters are provided. Those named after a color (red, green, blue, amber, salmon) do not limit the display to those colors, but convert the displayed image to grayscale first, then display that image in levels of the selected color. This preserves details that would otherwise be lost.
> Grayscale, **invert colors**, temperature adjustment and custom R/G/B adjustment filters are also provided.

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

For basic usage, set the **Master filter mode** to **Invert**.

<sub>Disclaimer: I don't have any relation with the app, its company and their developers. I just found this when trying to answer [the same issue on KitKat](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/97608/).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I use [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&referrer=utm_source%3Dhomepage) with this [flow](https://llamalab.com/automate/community/flows/31112).
It needs to set some permissions via ADB.

Answer (score -1):

### For Samsung devices with Android Lollipop 5.1.1:

Settings → Personalization → Accessibility → Vision
 → Negative colors

Comment: *You're [intentionally abusing](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/136086/revisions)* the use of formatting. Your post is not big or have multiple parts so there is no need to use top-level headings and preformatting is *completely unjustified* here.

Comment: You misunderstand. Andrew T. used quote tag because *he quoted text from description of a product*. It is justified there. Second, this is a Q&A site, not a typical forum where abuse of, or unnecessary highlighting is a  norm. Everyone here knows where a new answer starts and ends. There is no point in making an advert out of it. That said, I'm done here arguing. I've removed unnecessary quote tags but left the heading untouched. It should be fine with you now.