# Invert screen colors on Android 4.4. KitKat

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, accessibility, color

In Android Kitkat 4.4, is there a way to invert screen colors, that is make all colors negative? One would assume this would be a basic accessibility feature in today's world.

Comment: It's not available by default on AOSP KitKat. Which phone model do you have?

Comment: I have Micromax Canvas A1, based on the Android One specification. If it's not available by default are there any apps? (I couldn't find any for the 4.4). There seem to be a Negative Colors widget that is supposed to come in "stock", but I can't find it on my phone.

Comment: Someone suggested to install Xposed Framework, but I don't know if there's module for that. Other suggested [CF.lumen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.lumen) app, but needs root (I tried just now, it can invert properly).