# How do I invert colours inside a specific app?

Tags: screen, automation, quick-settings, color

The latest Android has an *Invert Colours* option in quick settings.

Is there any way to turn this on automatically when a specific app is opened? Is there any other way to achieve inversion of colours inside a specific app?

Comment: Are you rooted? Some apps can put a toggle in the notification shade so you could toggle it quickly, but it requires root.

Comment: @AndyYan Not rooted. Any workaround possible in that case?

Comment: None that I know of. Tasker might be able to do it somehow, but some actions of it also requires root, and I never used it so I don't know if doing it is one of the actions.

Comment: Tasker needs to run in the background and ultimately costs battery. This should be part of the OS itself. There are software vendors who try to sell dark mode for real money, it is ridiculous and needs to be fought back.

Answer (score 4):

For me Tasker did the job, but you need an additional Tasker plug in for this, called AutoTools.
On my bq android device root wasn't needed to do the job.
I set up a profile to invert the screen when I open specific apps like my newspaper reader.

Comment: What did you use to invert the screen?

Answer (score 2):

Since the answer is a little light on details for novice Tasker users (like me).

Here is how to do it step by step:

- Download and install [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)
- Free trial version [here](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/download.html)
- Import the example for Tasker from [here](https://taskernet.com/shares/?user=AS35m8k%2BaZLgCIb5T0nUApr4C48YVpR0pNYbQkX6gVkfSp0Tq8I6HZWvr73mQHrhGoQX0TB%2BC8qk%2Bhc%3D&id=Profile%3Ainverter)
- The example works for Gmail app and manipulates the accessibility_display_inversion_enabled property to toggle the color inversion. Making Gmail Dark but others app normal.
- Enable the profile
- Now, every time you click on gmail, if it doesn't work it's because it needs more permissions (check notifications)
- Add the "usage access" permissions and "write settings" permissions
- You also have to enable write settings perms via adb with 
  `adb shell pm grant net.dinglisch.android.taskerm android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`
- Click Gmail and color inverts
- Leave Gmail and color inverts back

Answer (score 0):

I use Automate, see this [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215575/302576). It is like Tasker and need the same permissions and preparatory actions via ADB but ligter than Tasker. And free for such small algorithms (less than 30 blocks).

Answer (score 0):

You can always turn invert on while your where you want to use it, then when you're done turn it off.
Go to settings on your phone, to accessability, to Direct access, check invert.
Now go back to your home page and rapidly push the home screen button 3 times, fast. It'll come on, push it 3 times again to turn it off. There is a video online for each step of you want to Google it.

Comment: This seems like customization from the manufacturer since it might not exist on all devices. It'd be great if you could [edit] and mention the phone model and the Android version. Thanks!